# list of dicts to memory for csv reader

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries. For example

```
l = [{'date': '2014-01-01', 'spent': '$3'},[{'date': '2014-01-02', 'spent': '$5'}]
```

I want to make this csv-like so if I want to save it as a csv I can.

I have other that gets a list and calls splitlines() so I can use csv methods.

for example:

```
reader = csv.reader(resp.read().splitlines(),  delimiter=',')
```

How can I change my list of dictionaries into a list that like a csv file?

I've been trying cast the dictionary to a string, but haven't had much luck.  It should be something like

```
"date", "spent"
"2014-01-01", "$3"
"2014-01-02", "$5"
```

this will also help me print out the list of dictionaries in a nice way for the user.

**update**

This is the function I have which made me want to have the list of dicts:

```
def get_daily_sum(resp):
    rev = ['revenue', 'estRevenue']
    reader = csv.reader(resp.read().splitlines(),  delimiter=',')
    first = reader.next()
    for i, val in enumerate(first):
        if val in rev:
            place = i
            break
        else:
            place = None
    if place:
        total = sum(float(r[place]) for r in reader)
    else:
        total = 'Not available'
    return total
```

so I wanted to total up a column from a list of column names. The problem was that the "revenue" column was not always in the same place.

Is there a better way?   I have one object that returns a csv like string, and the other a list of dicts.

Comment: Will all the dicts have the same keys?

Comment: yes. It is from an api callback.  All other responses come in as either xml or csv. just this one i'm working with returns this list of dicts.

Comment: read csv line by line into a list of lists. As soon as you have the data in such format, you can easily do whatever, convert it to your dict, sum columns etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using list comprehension, should work for any number of keys, but only if all your dicts have same heys.

```
l = [[d[key] for key in dicts[0].keys()] for d in dicts]
```

To attach key names for column titles:

```
l = dicts[0].keys() + l
```

This will return a list of lists which can be exported to csv:

```
import csv
myfile = csv.writer(open("data.csv", "wb")) 
myfile.writerows(l)
```

Comment: I like this so far. What if I wanted to pass l to csv.reader()? Maybe I should write to an io.BytesIO object as mentioned by @mgilson. I kind of want there to be a string that I can print, or if the user wants to then say, ok save it to csv, I'll have the object ready to pass along to a save function.   Or, if they don't want to save, but want to, lets say, add up the spent column, I could load the string into the csv reader option and sum up l[1] values.  See where I'm going?  Not sure if this is a good way to approach it.

Comment: @Ptrkcon You have a list and you can do whatever with it. You can print any element (row) of a list, you can save it to csv, you can do whatever. list *is* the object you need. I mean, I don't see why would you want a csv.reader here while you can do all the same things with the list, and in a much easier way... It just looks like an unnecessary step (convert list to csv, then read data from csv... to a list?? yes, what else...).

Comment: Hmm you're right.  I was using the csv reader just to add up a column but I could just do that with lists.  I'll post the function where I used it.  Let me know if there is an easier way. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

You would want to use `csv.DictWriter` to write the file.

```
with open('outputfile.csv', 'wb') as fout:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(fout, ['date', 'spent'])
    for dct in lst_of_dict:
        writer.writerow(dct)
```

Comment: I don't actually want to save a file though. I'd like to have it as a variable.  And if I want to save it later I can.

Comment: @Ptrkcon -- Then instead of using a file, you can write to a `io.BytesIO` object.